# Query for group by values from multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
ID key familyname  street     pin
1   1    xxx          abc      11
2   1    xxx          acf      13
3   1    xxx1         acf      13
4   1    xxx1         bcf      12
5   2    yyy          abc      11
6   2    yyy          abc      11
7   2    yyy1         bcj      13
8   2    yyy1         bck      14
9   2    yyy2         btj      15
10  2    yyy2         byj      16
```

Now I want to group street and pin based on columnn "familyname" for each individual key. For example I would expect the output for the above table to be

```
ID key familyname  street     pin
1   1    xxx        abc,acf    11,13

3   1    xxx1       acf,bcf    13,12

5   2    yyy        abc,abc    11,11

7   2    yyy1       bcj,bck    13,14

9   2    yyy2       btj,byj    15,16
```

It would be of great help if I can get some suggesion regarding the design  of the grouping query which could give me the result in a fashion as shown above

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has built-in functionality to concatenate rows for every group called `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT  MIN(ID) ID,
        `key`,
        familyName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(street) street,
        GROUP_CONCAT(pin) pin
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY `key`, familyName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/397ca/1)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═════╦════════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ KEY ║ FAMILYNAME ║ STREET  ║  PIN  ║
╠════╬═════╬════════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║   1 ║ xxx        ║ abc,acf ║ 11,13 ║
║  3 ║   1 ║ xxx1       ║ acf,bcf ║ 13,12 ║
║  5 ║   2 ║ yyy        ║ abc,abc ║ 11,11 ║
║  7 ║   2 ║ yyy1       ║ bcj,bck ║ 13,14 ║
║  9 ║   2 ║ yyy2       ║ btj,byj ║ 15,16 ║
╚════╩═════╩════════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```